# django page load slow in 10 seconds

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models, django-views

The page is loading in 10 seconds and after downloading django-debug-toolbar i saw that I am making 124 queries and 90% of them are duplicates.

```py
{% for tc in tb_terminal_categories %}
                        {% if not tc.parent %}
                            <li class="mt-2">
                                <span class="tree-span">
                                    <a href="{% url 'terminal-management' %}?category={{ tc.category_name }}">{{ tc.category_name }}</a>
                                    <a class="tree-child" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#terminal-category-modal"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                                    <a class="tree-child" href="{% url 'tb-terminal-category-delete' tc.id %}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                </span>
                                <ul>
                                    {% for tcc in tb_terminal_categories %}
                                        {% if tcc.parent == tc %}
                                            <li>
                                                <span class="tree-span">
                                                    <a href="{% url 'terminal-management' %}?category={{ tcc.category_name }}">{{ tcc.category_name }}</a>
                                                    <a class="tree-child" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#terminal-category-modal"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                                                    <a class="tree-child" href="{% url 'tb-terminal-category-delete' tcc.id %}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                                </span>
                                            </li>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

in this model I reference 4 other models, how do make this implementation work faster?

```py
class TbTerminalCategory(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32,
                          default=generate_uuid)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        TbCustomer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='cstm_id')
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category_desc = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='parent_id')
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()
    create_user = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tb_terminal_category'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_time = timezone.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.category_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure I need to see a template code, but based on the models I would recommend adding this `select_related` clause ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)):

```
...
terminals = terminals.select_related('customer', 'area', 'room', 'category', 'device_model')
page = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
...
```

Some of those may be excessive, check for usage in the template (like `terminal.category.name`) and remove if there are none.

Comment: I have added a chunk from templates, there is the problem

Comment: What problem? Does the `select_related` help with queries?

Comment: but anyways that wasn't the problem, I have reduced the problems from 120 queries to 40, still the page is loading in 4 seconds